# Firebase Query / TableView issue

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was following some outdated youtube tutorials and have been stuck on this issue for 3 days now. I am making a simple To-Do app. I want to display all of the names of the tasks in the database in the tableView.

The database is structured:

```
-Task
  -unique task ID
      -description
      -name
```

So I am trying to grab the names of all the tasks in the DB and display them in the tableView.

Here is what I have:

```
       ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
       var tasks: [Task] = []
       ref.child("Task").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: {  snapshot in


        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let taskName = snapshotValue?["name"] as? String
        let taskDescrip = snapshotValue?["description"] as? String

        let addTask = Task()
        addTask.descrip = taskDescrip!
        addTask.name = taskName!

        self.tasks.append(addTask)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    })
```

Everything prints as expected but when I add the code to render the names in the tableView cells, the app crashes every single time and prints

> "fatal error: Index out of range"

In regards to the `tasks[indexPath.row]`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tasks.count == 0 {
        return 1
    }

    return tasks.count
}


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if tasks.count == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No tasks"
    }

    let thisTask = tasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = thisTask.name

    return cell
}
```

Comment: the problem is caused by let thisTask = tasks[indexPath.row]. there are 0 elements in tasks and you are setting minimum number of rows to be 1. So, when accessing tasks[0], you got that error.

Comment: ref.child("Task") is listening for Task node...If your purpose is to listen to new childs added I think then you need to listen to "Task**s**" if that meet your structure and also you need to follow Nirav D answer for the tableView.

Comment: Thank you guys @Jad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `let thisTask = tasks[indexPath.row]` and `cell.textLabel?.text = thisTask.name` inside the `else` block of your `if` condition because your array is empty and it is trying to access the first object from it. So it should be like this.

```
if tasks.count == 0 {
    cell.textLabel?.text = "No tasks"
}
else {
    let thisTask = tasks[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = thisTask.name
}
return cell
```

**Note:** In Swift use native `Dictionary` and `Array` instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1):

add code in method "func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath:   IndexPath)"

...
if tasks.count == 0 {
        cell.textLabel?.text = "No tasks"
        return cell
    }

....
return cell
}